# How to show formatted html tags

Tags: php, tags, formatting

I have a div which is editable, my users adds content into it and sometimes they adds html tags and saves into the database, now when I retrieve the text using php it is showing me the html tags rather then formatting it.

For example:

```
<div id='content' contentEditable='true'>
   This is a html <a href='www.google.com' >formatted</a><strong>text</strong>
</div>
```

JavaScript, how I am posting:

```
var content = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
{post content}
```

PHP, how I am displaying:

```
echo $_POST['content'];
```

It is displaying the link with proper default blue colored and underlined but the `<strong>` and
`<bold>` tags display as it is without the default HTML format.

This is how I am getting :

> This is a html [formatted](http://www.google.com)`<strong>text<strong>`

This is how I wanted to display:

> This is a html [formatted](http://www.google.com) **text**

Answer (score 0):

Per what I can see your problem is caused by

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

Try to comment it out and see what happens.